# Update a sheet with slightly different lines each time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to follow and update a budget file. I receive monthly new excel file that gives me elements of a budget. I have this monthly information for several years. 
I want a way to implement a monthly monitoring on the past and a way update it easily each month. I therefore have something like a hundred files.

I receive each month a new excel file, named for instance for june *MBC_2018_06*, and I have several parts of a global budget, each one in a separate worksheet, and I am interested by the monitoring of some of these worksheets.

My problem is that I do not have necessarily the same rows each month. But I have sub totals and totals so that I have reference points. Here is an example of a worksheet I have to work with :

- Month 1

> ```
> Alfred        12
> John          3
> Mark          4
> Steven        6
> Subtotal 1    25
> Mary          45
> Emily         7
> Joan          16
> Margaret      4
> Sub total 2   72
> Total         97
> ```

- Month 2 :

> ```
> Alfred        11
> Mark          13
> Steven        23
> Subtotal 1    47
> Mary          17
> Victoria      23
> Emily         9
> Joan          25
> Elizabeth     18
> Margaret      2
> Subtotal 2    94
> Total         141
> ```

So I have sometimes more lines in one month, sometimes in the other, but I have each time the subtotals that force me to put each line in an implicit place.

What I would want from these two sheets would be :

> ```
> Alfred       12   11
> John         3    
> Mark         4    13
> Steven       6    23
> Subtotal 1   25   47
> Mary         45   17
> Victoria          23
> Emily        7    9
> Joan         16   25
> Elizabeth    18
> Margaret     4    2
> Subtotal 2   72   94
> Total        97   141
> ```

I would ideally want a solution that enables to quickly update that each month.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a master list of all the names?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What is possible -I am currently checking that- is that lines in month N are always included in month N+1, in which case I would have a changing master list, but a changing master list anyways.

Comment: How/where are names assigned to groups (subtotals)?  Are names ever subtotaled in a different group?

Comment: It is implicit in the file : you have some labels, then a subtotal, other labels, another subtotal and so on. A label cannot switch between different subtotal on different months. If it appears on one subtotal, it will stay on the same if it appears again.

Comment: This isn't a trivial task, so you might get pushback that the question is too broad.  It seems to me that any solution is going to require converting the data into more of a database structure, like creating a master list that expands as needed.  There are relationships "hidden" in the data that need to become explicit in order for Excel handle it intelligently.  Once you have a master list, it is straightforward to populate monthly data in the right place.

Comment: Does it matter if the solution is done with formulas or with vba?

Comment: I am not fluent in VBA, so I would instinctively prefer formulas. Additionnaly that would ease the communication with other people that my use the file. That being said, if the right tool to do such a thing is VBA and not formula, so be it and I will use it.

Comment: Pretty simple to do with VBA.  How is the data really stored?  Is each month on a separate worksheet?  Are the months really labelled `Month 1`, etc.

Comment: It should be possible using an array formula. If you just need two individual months like in your example it should be relatively easy. Do you just need two or more that's not clear from your question? Maybe, in addition to your example, you could describe your goal in a general way in your question.

Comment: @Albin I have in fact roughly a hundred files from the past, and my goal is double : have a proper monitoring of the past monthly data (for instance being able to tell if some given line is regular over time or very situated) and to be able to quickly update it when new data arrive;

Comment: @AnthonyMartin Your explanation of your data structure is not clear to me.  I assume by *file* you mean Workbook, and by *tab* you mean worksheet. In your post you mention monitoring *some* of the worksheets in each monthly workbook you receive (some means more than one), and in your comment you write about the worksheets being stored in folders.  But worksheets are not stored in folders; they are stored in workbooks.  Can you clarify please?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried to clarify again. I think your understandind is right. I have a monthly workbook, which I can store basically where I want (currently they are stored on yearly folders). And each workbook has several worksheets corresponding to several subparts. Some subparts (more than one) interest me, some not. For instance, I am interested in the *P200* worksheet of my *MBC_2018_06* workbook

Comment: @AnthonyMartin With the information you have provided, I can create a VBA routine that will iterate through a single workbook that has multiple worksheets, each a single month, and collate the data on a Summary worksheet. To iterate through the folders, workbooks and worksheets you have, will require significant modifications, and a familiarity with advanced VBA. Not enough information for me to do that and probably outside of the scope of this group. You might be able to set up a connection using Power Query (Excel 2010+; aka Get&Transform Excel 2016).

Comment: @AnthonyMartin sorry, I still don't really get what you want to do. So far what I understand: 1. you want to compare all persons of two months directly, 2. you want to see the data of one person for several months (how many? all?). Or do you want to have one sheet that has all the data from all the sheets (100+) you have? Also it is important for you that a new month can be added quickly.

Comment: @AnthonyMartin You also should add al the information we discussed into your original question, otherwise it gets really complicated to get all the single pieces of information out from all the different comments.

Answer (score -1):

Your question implies two requests:

1. To get a list names ever exited in monthly worksheet. From a database's point of view, this is in fact to get a union of names in monthly worksheet (removing duplicates);
2. To use the *full* list of names as key to lookup history budget in monthly worksheet;

If not seeking an automatically update, i.e. to manipulate the workbooks manually, the first goal can be achieved by:

a. Copying name list in history monthly worksheets together then uses *advanced filtering* with removing duplicates.
b. Once the *full name list* is got, later monthly update can be appending name list from new monthly to *old full name list* then re-filter it.

The second goal can be achieved by utilizing `vlookup` formula, referencing each monthly workbook/worksheet. You may need some tricks to generate the workbook's file name based the column number of referencing cell with `column` formula.

Again, you may need formula like `if(isna(vlookup(...)), "", vlookup(...)` to get rid of the `#N/A` text when a given name not found for some specific months.

Comment: I don't think the question necessarily implies those two requests. Granted, a "master list" would make things much easier (and it is a necessity for your solution), but creating it by manual copying data from 100+ worksheets, does not seem very efficient?! Same thing for the second goal referencing 100+ worksheets manually does not seem very efficient either?!

Also, maybe you could ad an example for how the formulas should be implemented.